# VMWare vSwitch VLAN IDs and tagged/untagged ports

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vlan, vswitch

Similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/443335/tagged-and-untagged-vlans):

> What happens when a port is configured as ACCESS and is a part of VLAN 'X' and we get a packet of VLAN 'Y' on that port? Will the switch drop it or it will add a VLAN header 'X' and forward to the respective port/ports (Double VLAN tagging).

Suppose I have the a switch stack (HP/3COM A5120) with a port range configured as

- Untagged: 1
- Tagged: None
- PVID: 1

connected to NICs on vSwitch0 has a local network set as VLAN 0. Traffic from that switch ends up on VLAN 1 inside the physical network and is routed correctly.

What will happen if I change the vSwitch VLAN ID to 1? Will the frames be dropped? Will they be double tagged? Will the tagging be stripped and the frames end up on VLAN 1?

I want to add another VM Port Group (VM network) to that vSwitch & a corresponding VLAN on the HP switch ports, but I'm wondering if I should explicitly assign the VLAN on the existing vSwitch port group first and whether doing so will break things.

Comment: I could tell you what this would look like on a Cisco (traffic coming into an access port will be checked for vlan tags, if a tag is present it must match the access vlan or be dropped - all allowed packets will end up with a single vlan tag matching the access port's vlan number), but not sure what this switch will do.

Comment: @ShaneMadden the product doc suggests likewise, but I haven't been able to replicate this. I may have to attach wireshark to a trunk port and see what's happening (though QinQ is supposed to be disabled by default).

Comment: Yeah, letting a tag through an access port and keeping it creates an opportunity for vlan hopping, so hopefully that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following from the [product manuals](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/manualsResults/?sp4ts.oid=4174705):

[image]

This doesn't seem to match the behaviour I observed (frames were being dropped), so I've ended up using a trunk port instead and making sure the VLAN I'm using on my vSwitch is permitted on the trunk port.